# How to "cancel" window.scroll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have a couple of divs with scrollbars in. Obviously, when it gets to the bottom of those divs, the rest of the body starts to scroll. Not ideal.

The "position:fixed;" trick on body doesn't work correctly due to the layout of other divs, so I put together a small solution that sets the window scroll position to the current scroll when hovering over one of the divs. Here's the code:

```
$(".scrollLock").hover( function() {    
    var scrollX = window.scrollX, scrollY = window.scrollY;
window.onscroll = function(e){
    scroll(scrollX,scrollY)
}
}, function() {
    var scrollX = window.scrollX, scrollY = window.scrollY;
window.onscroll = function(e){
    scroll() 
}
});
```

Obviously that second `scroll()` isn't correct. Whilst it works, it fills the console with errors as it's expecting two arguments. However, if I remove it, the scroll position stays locked even when I mouseout of the `scrollLock` div. Is there a more correct way of doing this?

Comment: I use `margin-top` and calculate it from `$(window).scrollTop()`. Works fine. And handle `$(window).on('scroll', function...)`

Comment: Ideally: do not change default, expected browser functionality

Comment: The scrollLock element is a little like that friends bar on the very right hand side of Facebook, which behaves the same :^)

Comment: Facebook uses `position:fixed` for right and then left columns. It requires very specific layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `e.preventDefault()`.

Although that may not work for scrolling.